# Checked symbol in checkbox is not visible unless the element is hover

Tags: qt, qt4, pyside

In a Qt application, I have a button which later with some code I attach a menu to it. Each element of the menu is a checkable `QAction`. The interesting thing is that once the element is check, the check sign isn't visible unless you hover it with the mouse. Here is a screenshot:

[image: enter the image]

I have some custom QCSS set, however, I have never added any style for `QAction` or anything, here it is:

```
QMainWindow, QDialog { background: #E8E8E8; color: #2e2e2e; }

QMenuBar, QStatusBar {
    background: #545454;
    color: #fff;
}

QLabel#lblBanner {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0.01, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #545454, stop: 1 #141414);
    margin: 0;
}

QMenu {
    background: #E8E8E8;
}
QMenuBar::item {
    background: transparent;
}

QMenuBar::item:selected {
    background: #444442;
    border: 0;
}

QMenuBar::item:pressed {
    background: #444442;
}

QMenu::item:selected {
    background: #cfcfcf;
}

QGroupBox {
    background: #fff;
    /* border: 1px solid white; */
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    padding: 18px 5px 10px 5px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

QGroupBox::title {
    subcontrol-origin: margin;
    subcontrol-position: top left;
    color: black;
    font-style: bold;
    /* padding: 4px 5px; */
    margin-left: 6px;
    margin-top: 7px;
    background: transparent;
    color: #2e2e2e;
}

QPushButton, QDialogButtonBox {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #f5f5f5, stop: 1 #cfcfcf); 
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 1px;
    min-width: 30px ;
}

QPushButton:hover, QDialogButtonBox:hover {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #cfcfcf, stop: 1 #b5b5b5);
}

QPushButton:pressed, QDialogButtonBox:pressed {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                stop: 0 #b5b5b5, stop: 1 #cfcfcf);
}

QPushButton:default, QDialogButtonBox:default {
    border: 1px solid;
    border-color: orange; /* make the default button prominent */
}

QPushButton[enabled=false]
{
    background: #ededed;
    color: #cfcfcf;
}

QLineEdit, QTextEdit {
    background: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0, x2: 0, y2: 0.3,
                                stop: 0 #f2f2f2, stop: 1 white);
    border: 2px solid #E8E8E8;
    selection-background-color: orange;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 3px;
}

QHeaderView::section {
    background-color: qlineargradient(x1: 0, y1: 0.01, x2: 0, y2: 1,
                                      stop: 0 #545454, stop: 1 #141414);
    color: white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border: 1px solid #6c6c6c;
}

QTreeWidget {
    border: 2px solid #E8E8E8;
    border-radius: 5px;
    selection-background-color: orange;
    show-decoration-selected: 1;
}

/* QTreeWidget::item:selected { */
/*     background: ; */
/* } */

QTreeWidget::item:selected:!active {
    background: #e59500;
}

QTreeWidget::item:selected:active {
    background: #f29d00;
}

QTreeWidget::item:hover {
    background: orange;
}

QTreeWidget::branch {
    background: white;
}

/* barra de desplazamiento */
/* Vertical */
QScrollBar:vertical {
    background: #fff;
    width: 10px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:vertical {
    background: #E8E8E8;
}

/* Horizontal */
QScrollBar:horizontal {
    background: #fff;
    height: 10px;
}

QScrollBar::handle:horizontal {
    background: #E8E8E8;
}
/* Fin de la barra de desplazamiento */

QProgressBar {
    border: 2px solid orange;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

QProgressBar::chunk {
    background: orange;
    margin: 2px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

What can be the problem and in which way could I fix this?

Comment: Do you still have the problem if you remove the custom CSS ?

Comment: @tmoreau Not at all! What could it be?

Comment: @tmoreau Ah! The issue is happens if `QMenu {background: #E8E8E8;}` is specified!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
QMenu::indicator:checked
{
    image: url(:/icons/checkbox_checked);
}
```

Sometimes specifying *some* QSS elements denies relying on the OS defaults and you have to specify everything yourself.